# how to get distinct in XMLDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

i am trying to get the `Distinct` from the XMLDocument and load into the Dropdownlist.

```
var topicNodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//content:Topic", nsmgr).Cast<XmlNode>().Select(c =>   c.InnerText).Distinct();
```

here is my full code:

```
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();//xml doc used for xml parsing
    xdoc.Load(url);    
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("content", "sitename.xsd");

    var topicNodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//content:Topic", nsmgr).Cast<XmlNode>().Select(c =>   c.InnerText).Distinct();  

    foreach (XmlNode node in topicNodes)
    {
        string topic = node.Attributes["TopicName"].Value;
        //dropdownlist.items.add(new listitem(topic);
        this.dropdownlist.Items.Add(new  ListItem(topic);  
    }
    dropdownlist.databind();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve, does this not return a distinct set of results?

Comment: Why aren't you using `XElement`?

Comment: Your code sample contains a syntax error.

Comment: Use linq to xml and using linq you can get the distinct values easily.

Comment: Check this code too static IEnumerable<int> GetOwners(XDocument doc, string cat)
{
        return from item in doc.Descendants("item")
                where item.Attribute("cat").Value == cat
                select (int)item.Attribute("owner")).Distinct();

}

Comment: @Abu And you still have a syntax error...

Comment: can you tell me what syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Linq to XML?

Otherwise create a key value array and use the value to distinct on as key.

Edit:

Your distincting on the InnerText is that the correct value? Try to distinct first and then select the innerText.

Try

```
var topicNodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//content:Topic", nsmgr).Cast<XmlNode>()**.Distinct()**.Select(c => c.InnerText).ToList();
```

Edit2:

Use this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
     (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

You have to select on witch field you would like to distinct. The XmlNode with the same ID is not the same object!

Comment: i am open to use linq to xml... i started using it but got stuck and thats why i go to use the xmldocument route...

Comment: 'var topicNodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//content:Topic", nsmgr).Cast<XmlNode>().Select(c => c.InnerText).First().Distinct();' i try first and then distinct still the same

Comment: Isn't there a //content:Id or something to distinct on?

Comment: i tried the your updated code it does return my all (without distinct) and all the topicname was empty (no data in it)